# how do I run a defined function multiple times with a for statement so that the return compounds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new at Python and have a defined function for doubling a number.  I want to double the number three times using a for statement. This is from lesson 6.3 in Dan Bader's Python Basics.  For some reason, this one has me stumped.

Below, I tried adding:
number = number * 2   after my for statement but my result is 
20
40
80

```
def doubles(number):
    """Takes one number as its input and doubles it."""
    double = number * 2
    return double


number = 5


for x in range(0, 3):
    print(doubles(number))
```

Actual results are:
10
10
10

Expected results are:
10
20
40

Comment: You are discarding the result of the `double` function each time you call it in the loop. So `number` never changes, since you never assign to it. `int` objects are immutable, so no operations you perform on them will modify them in-place, and since your function works entirely with local variables and returns the value (a generally good way to do things) then there is no way for `number` to be modified by your function. You need to assign the result of the call to `doubles` back to `number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def doubles(number):
    """Takes one number as its input and doubles it."""
    double = number * 2
    return double


number = 5


for x in range(0, 5):
    print(doubles(number))
    number=doubles(number)
```

Comment: made it range(0,5) just to check results. if you want only 3 results just change it to 3

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do!  Many thanks!!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to call `doubles` twice for each value of `numbers`?

Comment: you can just multiply it by 2. but this gives broad view for other implementation too.

Comment: i mean this does not even require a function you can just do print(2*number) and remove the function.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `number` (the global one) to retain the result of calling `doubles`; so do that explicitly:

```
for x in range(0,3):
    number = doubles(number)
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the numbers over each other like this.
'number = number + number' in short "number += number"
best,
i hope its easier to see it when you write it like this.

```
number = 5
for x in range(0, 3):
    double =  number * 2
    print(double)
    number += number
```

Answer (score 0):

you are incrementing x but not change the value of "number" along the way

```
def doubles(number):
    """Takes one number as its input and doubles it."""
    double = number * 2
    return double


number = 5


for x in range(0, 3):
    print(doubles(number))
    number*=2
```

Comment: This isn't using `x`, either.

Comment: @ScottHunter i am using x to limit the number of times number is varied

Comment: So was the original code, which you said was not using it.

Comment: @ScottHunter i hope the edit satisfies the quality of  "Answering Questions"

Comment: It is very poor design to duplicate logic; if you wanted to change this to, say, tripling `number` each iteration, you'd have to keep code in 2 places in sync.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution with minimum coding.

def double(a):

```
print(a)

for b in range(1,5):

    b = a * 2

    a = b

    print(a)
```

double(10)